# Most efficient implementation of passing parameters through objects from a OOP design perspective?

Tags: java, android, oop, parameter-passing

[image]

I want to make a method for creating an arbitrary amount of Player-objects (stored in an ArrayList in PlayLogic). For now I've decided on just creating 2 Player-objects. I'm hardcoding this in PlayActivity by calling `createPlayers(2)`, so the implementation of this.. is it better to pass the parameter to Play which then passes the parameter to PlayLogic which creates 2 Player-objects.. or is it better if I directly call PlayLogic from PlayActivity?
I want my design to reflect efficient design (so I want as few relations as possible, not sure if this is the correct UML-term..).

Comment: Worried about the efficiency of 1 - one - extra method call? Seriously?

Comment: @ignis while it may be a linear scale, 12 trillion extra calls is 12 trillion extra calls.

Comment: @ignis Not as much of the efficiency/performance of the program (in terms of clock cycles) as efficiency from a design perspective, I want to make this program and its source code easy to overlook and maintain while retaining the same flexibility and "complexity" without adding any unnecessary overhead (of course I won't super-optimize it, but want to do it as easy to understand and further develop as possible). "efficiency" may have been the wrong term to use...

Comment: @Woot4Moo I don't think he will need to invoke the Player factory method more than 1 time...

Comment: @ignis That's right, I'll probably only have to invoke it once when I start the game, (I'll invoke it again if I exit the game and start it up again, or change the number of players) but it's not going to be invoked frequently. Regardless, I'd like to make sure that the design is proper.

Comment: Then it depends on what do Play/PlayLogic do. If Play is nothing more than a wrapper for the gui and the logic, then I'd get rid of it.

Comment: This is off-topic but I will reply to your comment.
Yes Play is just a wrapper/controller.
However I decided to use it as its own class because PlayActivity is the Activity started when I start the app (at this point), but it may not be the entrypoint of the app (at a later point), so I'm using PlayActivity to simulate what it would be like to f.e. enter the name and number of players and then start the game.
I guess this could be done in an initialization method of PlayActivity and I could get rid of Play but I rather not because it is easier to overlook the whole program this way..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a trivial amount of overhead that comes about from having an extra layer in the process.  This overhead is not enough to dictate muddying a design (improper abstraction).  The reason why there is extra overhead is because you are asking someone else for information in the multi-layered approach.  For instance:

2 People can communicate with each other faster than 3 people can with the same information, follow the example below:

```
A -> B (what is 2+2)  
B-> A (4) 

VICE

A->B (what is 2+2)  
B->C (what is 2+2)  
C->B (4)  
B->A(4)
```

Further you talk of performance, but have opted to use an `ArrayList`, it could be the case that this data structure is incorrect, we would need more information about the underlying object model and the operations that will be performed most often during execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So I think I'm going to call PlayLogic directly from PlayActivity.
Regarding the usage of ArrayList, would it be better to use it in the following manner:
`List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<Player>` ?
I'm opting to use ArrayList because I want to use an arbitrary amount of players, but I'm starting with 2 players (to make sure it works with few sources of errors), should I instead simply use a Player[] (Player-array)?

Comment: So ArrayList will resize as it gets close to being full.  And an ArrayList is coincidentally backed by an array which will put you in the same spot.

Comment: Ok, so it really doesn't matter whether I use ArrayList and array in this case?

Comment: Correct, what I was getting at is maybe List isn't the right implementation.  You may want to consider Map or Set or Tree etc

Comment: This discussion is off-topic but I will answer your comment.
I'd rather use List or ArrayList because I'm more comfortable working with those structures, I'm guessing they have no negative impact on performance or code readability so I'll stick to using them.